# 'GMT-05:00) EST' option unexpectedly included in time_zone_select dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

(With Rails 3.2.20, ruby 1.9.3)

In my website in production the '(GMT-05:00) EST' option is unexpectedly included in the `time_zone_select` dropdown:

[image: img]

This timezone does not exists in [`ActiveSupport::TimeZone::MAPPING`](http://git.io/vmOgA). It is injected [`ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map`](http://git.io/vmO2V):

```
def zones_map
    @zones_map ||= begin
      new_zones_names = MAPPING.keys - lazy_zones_map.keys
      new_zones       = Hash[new_zones_names.map { |place| [place, create(place)] }]

      lazy_zones_map.merge(new_zones)
    end
  end
```

on the line `lazy_zones_map.merge(new_zones)` because `lazy_zones_map` contains the "EST" zone.

It does not happen on my development box **and does not happen in my Rails production console**: `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.send :lazy_zones_map` returns `{"UTC"=>(GMT+00:00) UTC}`.

But when I put in my view in production

`<%= ActiveSupport::TimeZone.send :lazy_zones_map %>`

I get `{"UTC"=>(GMT+00:00) UTC, "EST"=>(GMT-05:00) EST}`. I don't understand why it happens, any idea?

The [`#lazy_zones_map`](http://git.io/vmOrp) definition is

```
def lazy_zones_map
  require_tzinfo

  @lazy_zones_map ||= Hash.new do |hash, place|
    hash[place] = create(place) if MAPPING.has_key?(place)
  end
end
```

EDIT: the same version of tzinfo is used in production and development, 0.3.44 (I've checked with the command `Gem.loaded_specs["tzinfo"]`).

Comment: If this does not happen in `production` `rails console` then it's likely an issue due to the use of `||=` assignment operator.  You could test restarting the production server so that the `@lazy_zones_map` gets reassigned or you could simply use `=` instead of `||=` for testing purposes.  e.g. `@lazy_zones_map = Hash.new`

Comment: @vee thanks for your help. Restarting the production server does not fix the issue but `@lazy_zones_map = Hash.new` does. I don't understand why though. Can you explain? Thanks!

Comment: @vee finally found the cause, we had in a controller filter the line `Time.zone = 'EST'` and changing to `Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` fixes the issue.